# What benefits will a professional usability study give me over a guerilla one?

Tags: usability-study

By 'professional' study, I mean hiring an outside company to run the test (typically $10k+).  By 'guerilla' I mean hallway testing, or 'Rocket Surgery made easy' style testing.

What is the benefit of the paid-for study?

Comment: There are a *lot* of things in-between the two -- are those off the table & the focus is just on the question you asked about what you get with an agency?

Comment: I guess my question is really around what do I get over and above a guerilla test. So they are on the table. Should I edit the question?

Comment: maybe? I mean, there are agencies that charge 10k+ & don't do much, and agencies that do a lot & don't charge 10k+, and a lot of in-house "guerrilla" work that gets a lot done, so for a useful answer it might be good to tease out the nuances of the situation.

Comment: @jcmeloni I was going to edit but the answers below have addressed what I intended.

Comment: It depends on how good your internal research capabilities are, and how good the external agency is... Hopefully you know exactly what you are getting for 10k :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preliminary remark: The list of benefits might be a bit different depending on your type of product and company size.

**Benefits** you *can* get from hiring an agency:

- **Questions** to better understand your product and for a proper test setup, which can already be enlightening
- Eventally a **Heuristic Review upfront** (aka Expert Review) to get to the hypothesis they want to test (can also be helpful itself)
- **Save time**, i.e. on recruiting testers and organizing the test sessions themselfs
- Often **recruiting users matching your target group** is done for you
- If done externally, then you'll get a **room with all the equipment** like a usability lab with observation room and one-way-mirror, camera/microphone, recording sofware etc.
- **A list of all the 'usability bugs'** they found, along with **video** recorded and hopefully a **highlight video** that you can show e.g. to the management
- **Credibility** - especially in larger companies agency testing can pay off in terms of  credibility of the results
- Usually **addresses concerns and/or **avoids discussions** around the target group, small number of testers delivering sound results etc. - if not, the **agency will advocate** here
- Some agencies offer **consulting based on the results they found** how to improve things
- 'Access to more expertise' as separate point, brought up by PhillipW (thanks!)

The question was about benefits you can get from professional agency testing. Given a good agency I think professional testing can be really beneficial, especially if the company has't investing much time in testing so far. However, **I think that guerilla can also be very beneficial**, sometimes even way more than agency testing. But this would be off topic as the question is about the benefits of agency testing and not comparing the two.

Comment: The subject line of the question to me suggests that a comparison is what's being asked for...

Comment: @PhillipW Hope I got some points addressed here. Feel free to add to this :-)

Comment: Editing other people's responses feels sort of 'wrong' !  The only thing I'd add to your list is my 'access to more expertise' comment in my answer.

Comment: I am fine with others editing my posts, if in the interest of creating a great knowledge base. Anyway, thanks for the comment - added your point to the list above. Cheers!  @PhillipW

Answer (score 2):

Access to more expertise.  I'd say it was almost impossible to quantify this though.

An expert may just pick up one extra problem - but it could be the one 'killer problem' which is most important to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Trust and Credibility. You know when you pay a credible source, assuming that the consultants credentials are valid, that the results are trustworthy and reliable. You can use them inside your organization as a tool to convince management and sponsors. You will have higher chance of getting usability improvements implemented.

A guerilla test is not reliable, but it can still be accurate. The problem is that you don't know if the guerilla test is accurate or not. I would be reluctant to use a guerilla test as a tool to convince anyone. It would be shredded to pieces before I could say my first "But...".

As in many other things in life: What you pay is what you get ([WYPIWYG](http://www.acronymfinder.com/WYPIWYG.html))